# How to call a function in one class from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a function insert in the seViewController.m. I want to call this from first.m. How can i call this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of `seViewController.m` in `first.m`, by using the line: `seViewController *seView = [[seViewController alloc] init];` (change options in init if needed).

Then, use `[seView insert];`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very vague question about a very elementary topic. I seriously suggest reading a book about Objective-C programming.

That said, I can guess you need something like the following (in first.m):

```
#import "seViewController.h"
...
seViewController* seView = [seViewController new];
...
[seView insert];
...
```